# I'm using django-autoslug by ceol. I don't want unicode characters in my slug. How to do it?

Tags: python, django

https://github.com/ceol/django-autoslug
How to edit it if i don't want unicode characters? Just letters and numbers without foreign language characters.

I'm sure that i need to edit this part of code, but I don't know how. It's part of: https://github.com/ceol/django-autoslug/blob/master/autoslug/utils.py

```
 a URL with these characters included would confuse users and
# machines alike, so it's best to replace them; however, we
# still want Unicode characters in foreign languages to appear
pattern = r'[^\s\/\?\-\.\[\]\$\+\^\'"_~:#@!&()*,;=%]+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=lambda instance: instance.title.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed autoslug by ceol to this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug - its create slug with only ascii characters.